# Chinese Verse: Is "Broaden One's Horizons" a Translation That Makes Sense?

Tags: poetry

Here's the verse in question, the last verse of a Chines language poem:

"如再宽阔些便可知千里阵云怎么写了"

My current translation:

"If you broaden your horizons, you can learn how to write about vast formations of clouds."

Is "broaden horizons" a good way to translate "如再宽阔些便可知..."?

Comment: Got a bit more of that poem? A link?

Comment: "Broaden your horizons" mostly refers to "开阔眼界" in china. Any more context plz.

Answer (score 1):

You have: 如再宽阔些便可知千里阵云怎么写了

[This](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9B%A8%E9%9C%96%E9%93%83%C2%B7%E5%AF%92%E8%9D%89%E5%87%84%E5%88%87/10182399?fr=aladdin) is similar to yours, (maybe yours is a reference??):

念去去⑦，千里烟波，暮霭沉沉楚天阔⑧。
Memories wander, 10000 leagues of mist covered water, (here) dense evening mists (but in) Chu skies are clear
⑦去去：重复“去”字，表示行程遥远。

⑧“暮霭”句：傍晚的云雾笼罩着南天，
muai phrase: evening mists shroud the southern sky,
深厚广阔，
deep and wide,
不知尽头。
seemingly boundless.
暮霭（ǎi）：
muai:
傍晚的云雾。沈沈：即“沉沉”，
evening mists deep deep: namely "(lie) heavy",
深厚的样子。楚天：指南方楚地的天空。
appearing profound.
楚天：指南方楚地的天空。
Chu sky: refers to the clear skies of the Southern Chu Province